# Keras LSTM model

Tags: python, keras-layer, tf.keras

I cannot find a hands on tutorial on how to structure the data for use with keras LSTM.

**Data**

x_train = 7300 rows where each vector is length 64.

y_train = array of 7300 items either 0's or 1's (the class).

**Model**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, input_shape = (1, 64)))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
               epochs = 5,
               batch_size = 32,
               validation_split = 0.1,
               callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, min_delta=0.0001)])
```

My question is simply, why doesn't this work? Why isn't is as simple as giving an 2d array of vectors and similar length y values to fit.

Comment: _My question is simply, why doesn't this work?_ What happens instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras LSTM expects input of shape `[batch_size, timesteps, features]`. Your data is of shape `[batch_size, features]`.

To add the `timestep` dimension (where number of timesteps is 1), do the following:

```
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=1)
```